# Python Code optimization to minimum lines

Tags: python, optimization

How to optimize this python code as I need to minimize the number of lines used

```
        if Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_1":
                executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["C"].sum()
                print(executable_df.to_string())
        elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_2":
                executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y','L'])["C"].sum()
                print(executable_df.to_string())
        elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_3":
                executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["N"].sum()
                print(executable_df.to_string())
        elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_4":
                executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["O"].sum()
                print(executable_df.to_string())
        elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_5":
                executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["H","D"].sum()
                print(executable_df.to_string())
        elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_6":
                executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["T"].sum()/1024/1000
                executable_df = executable_df.astype({'T': 'int'})
                #print(executable_df.dtypes)
                print(executable_df.to_string())
        elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_7":
                executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y','U'])["T"].sum()/1024/1000
                executable_df = executable_df.astype({'T': 'int'})
                #print(executable_df.dtypes)
                print(executable_df.to_string())
        elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_8":
                executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y','L'])["V"].sum()
                print(executable_df.to_string())
```

It a kind of script that takes an csv sheets then output another filtered csv sheet with based on the filters that I did in the groupby function.

Comment: Well for one, you can just put `print(executable_df.to_string())` once at the end and save a bunch of lines that way. Also it might be more optimal to call `Graphsshown.get()` only once at the beginning, so you aren't calling `get()` over and over.

Comment: You could eliminate most of the conditionals by using a dictionary.

Comment: @RandomDavis you are right for regarding the print, I still can't understand your point for calling the `Graphshown.get()` once at the beginning?

Comment: @mahmoudosama I meant you assign its result to a temporary variable - like `graphs_shown = Graphsshown.get()`, and then you can just compare like `if graphs_shown  == "DATA_1"`. It'd just make things a bit clearer and also help with any potential future refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to cut a few lines is to print AFTER you check conditions.

```
    if Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_1":
            executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["C"].sum()
    elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_2":
            executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y','L'])["C"].sum()
    elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_3":
            executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["N"].sum()
    elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_4":
            executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["O"].sum()
    elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_5":
            executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["H","D"].sum()
    elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_6":
            executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y'])["T"].sum()/1024/1000
            executable_df = executable_df.astype({'T': 'int'})
    elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_7":
            executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y','U'])["T"].sum()/1024/1000
            executable_df = executable_df.astype({'T': 'int'})
    elif Graphsshown.get() == "DATA_8":
            executable_df = df.groupby(['x','y','L'])["V"].sum()
            
    print(executable_df.to_string())
```